# I don't understand this recursive method in python to generate permutations

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, permutation

How does this recursive method work to generate permutations given a string? Could someone explain me please?

```
def exchange(self, s):
    if 0 == len(s):
        yield s
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for p in self.exchange(s[:i] + s[i + 1:]):
                yield [s[i]] + p
```

Comment: It's called a ["generator"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: @rickdenhaan: I think that was clear. I think the OP has more problems with understanding the internal workings of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has the following idea:  Deliver all permutations by choosing one element from the input and then deliver all permutations of the *remaining* elements, prepended by the chosen element.  After this, repeat with another element.

So, if you have as input [0, 1, 2], then the code uses the first element (0) and builds all permutations of the remaining elements (1 and 2).  (These permutations are [1, 2] and [2, 1] of course.)

Then it delivers (yields) the 0 prepended to [1, 2] and then the 0 prepended to [2, 1], i. e. [0, 1, 2] and [0, 2, 1].

Then it continues and chooses the next element (1).  It then builds the permutations of the remaining elements (0, 2) (i. e. [0, 2] and [2, 0]).

And so forth.